# How to draw an arrow in an R plot where the x axis is a time axis?

Tags: r, datetime, plot

I would like to plot vertical arrows in a plot, the x axis must be a time axis.
The arrows must go from `my_data$from` to `my_data$to`.

I tried this snippet but no arrows is drawn.

```
my_data <- data.frame(timestamp=c("11:20:50","15:07:59","17:44:02"),from=c(0,1,2),to=c(1,3,1))
my_data$timestamp <- strptime(my_data$timestamp, "%H:%M:%S")
midnight <- strptime("00:00:00","%H:%M:%S")
plot(my_data$timestamp,my_data$from)
arrows(x0=my_data$timestamp-midnight,y0=my_data$from,x1=my_data$timestamp-midnight,y1=my_data$to,col='red')
```

[image]

What am I missing?

Comment: @G.Grothendieck Thank you, it works. If you transform your comment into an answer I will be very happy to accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this and modify as required:

```
with(my_data, arrows(x0 = as.numeric(timestamp), y0 = from, y1 = to, col = 'red'))
```

For example:

```
my_data <- data.frame(
  timestamp = as.POSIXct(c("11:20:50", "15:07:59","17:44:02"), format = "%H:%M:%S"),
  from = c(0,1,2),
  to = c(1,3,1))

plot(to ~ timestamp, my_data, type = 'n', ylim = range(from, to))
with(my_data, arrows(x0 = as.numeric(timestamp), y0 = from, y1 = to, col = 'red'))
```

[image: screenshot]